# Way to automatically install extensions?

Tags: extension

Is there a way to automatically install and enable CiviCRM extensions? Is it possible to do this via drush on a Drupal install for example? Or is use if the UI required?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [cv cli tool](https://github.com/civicrm/cv) provides the following commands for working with extensions:

```
ext:disable             Disable an extension
ext:download            Download and enable an extension
ext:enable              Enable an extension
ext:uninstall           Uninstall an extension and purge its data
ext:upgrade-db          Apply DB upgrades for any extensions
ext:list                List extensions (local and remote)
```

To see the full list of commands, type `cv` in your console.

Or if you prefer `drush` (Drupal only):

```
civicrm-ext-disable    Disable a CiviCRM extension.                                                                                      
 (ced)                                                                                                                                   
civicrm-ext-install    Install a CiviCRM extension.                                                                                      
 (cei)                                                                                                                                   
civicrm-ext-list       List of CiviCRM extensions enabled.                                                                               
 (cel)                                                                                                                                   
civicrm-ext-uninstall  Uninstall a CiviCRM extension.                                                                                    
 (ceui)
```

Answer (score 4):

[civicrm-buildkit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit) uses

```
drush cvapi extension.install
```

eg

```
drush -y -u admin cvapi extension.install key=org.civicrm.module.cividiscount debug=1
```

Using the Drush commands as Coleman says is probably easier (no `-u admin` at least), but adding this method for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use eg

```
cv ext:download ca.civicrm.logviewer
```

which would give an output of

```
Using extension feed "https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=4.7.27|uf=Drupal|status=stable|ready=ready"

Downloading extension "ca.civicrm.logviewer" (https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.logviewer/archive/1.1.zip)
```

and which unzips and renames the extension correctly and enables it. Job done!