# Manually uninstall an extension

Tags: extension

I installed the i10n extension on 4.7.24 and it totally FUBARed parts of the admin interface, I only get a blank screen.
How can I manually remove the extension (Extension menu is FUBARed too).

Answer (score 2):

Not quite an answer to the question, but if you didn't know, there is civicrm_extension table and you can at least set it to not active

otherwise if you have cli (and eg are on Drupal) you can use

- drush ceui

other such commands are listed [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3884/way-to-automatically-install-extensions)

Comment: Ah  ... that's good to know. drush is drupal only, if I remember correctly? This is on the Joomla cms.

Comment: correct. i amended answer to point out Drupal, from memory WP also has similar.